# NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject giving 0 element

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I am sending custom object dictionary from iPhone to apple watch but in watch interface i am getting 0 element array. Could you please help me on the same issue.

```
NSData* data=[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dic];
        [[self session] sendMessageData:data replyHandler:^(NSData * _Nonnull replyMessageData) {
            DDLogVerbose(@"pass");
        } errorHandler:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
            DDLogVerbose(@"fail with error %@",error);
        }];
```

and in watchkit

```
    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessageData messageData: Data, replyHandler: @escaping (Data) -> Void) {

        if let array = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: messageData) as? NSArray {
} // Here i am getting 0 element in array

}
```

Comment: Assuming `custom object dictionary` is an `NSDictionary`, `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: messageData) as? NSDictionary` should give non-nil value. Nil value seems result from casting  `NSDictionary` to `NSArray` instead of iphone-watch communication

Comment: nope custom object is NSMutableArray of NSDictionary

Comment: Did you find a solution ?